# Is it possible to get rid of the extra number tag for intermediate equations?

Tags: amsmath

With overleaf

this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{tag_tes}
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a
&= b+1 \\
&= c+2 \tag{3-2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

gives this output

[image]

which puts an extra (1) pointed out by the red arrow there.

Is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: \notag or \nonumber or if the intention is to have a single number denoting the whole alignment use `\begin{equation}` with a nested `\begin{aligned}` rather than `\begin{align}`

Comment: note automatic numbering is the usual case, manual numbering using `\tag`  is an over-ride for special occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make more familiar with writing math in LaTeX by read som introductory text like [advance math](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics).

**Edit:**
In your case, if I understood your question correctly, you can write on one of the following ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:split}\tag{3-1}
\begin{split}
a   & = b+1 \\
    & = c+2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
See \eqref{eq:split} ...
\begin{align}
a   & = b+1     \notag\\
    & = c+2     \label{eq:align}    \tag{3-2}
\end{align}
See \eqref{eq:align} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to keep the tag and the last `=` in the same line?

Comment: @JJJohn You can set the `tbtags` split for `amsmath`.

Comment: @JJJohn, see edited answer.